# How to Use Multiple Cookies with same name

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

Similar:

[Multiple cookies with same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924900/multiple-cookies-with-same-name)

[How to handle multiple cookies with the same name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056306/how-to-handle-multiple-cookies-with-the-same-name)

---

I am setting a cookie on the page load of my asp control. I have a function gets the cookie and stores it in a `var` to be used. My question is, after reading the msdn site on cookies, is should I get the cookie from the `Request` or the `Response` and then set value of the other? Or should I get the cookie from the `Response` and set it's value? The last one doesn't seem quite right but I don't know.

MSDN text:

`The browser is responsible for managing cookies on a user system. Cookies are sent to the browser via the HttpResponse object that exposes a collection called Cookies. You can access the HttpResponse object as the Response property of your Page class. Any cookies that you want to send to the browser must be added to this collection. When creating a cookie, you specify a Name and Value. Each cookie must have a unique name so that it can be identified later when reading it from the browser. Because cookies are stored by name, naming two cookies the same will cause one to be overwritten.`

I assumed that I should get it from the `request` and set the `response` cookie, that doesn't seem to be quite right because I have ended up with double cookies with different values. The cookie I am worried about is `TRACKINGINFO`. It is set on a different sub domain and I need to pick up the value and just add to it and re-set the value.

Here is the request headers from Google Chrome:

`ASP.NET_SessionId=bi2ingjjk5f4nhm; referer_domain=dev-znode.local; referer_query=; TRACKINGINFO=1234%2C526%2C1234%2C526; __utma=251778844.1427755012.1389292549.1389292549.1389292549.1; __utmb=251778844.16.10.1389292549; __utmc=251778844; __utmz=251778844.1389292549.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); ZNodeCookie; LocaleID=43; TRACKINGINFO=1234%2C526%2C1234%2C526,2508`

Request headers:

`TRACKINGINFO=1234%2C526%2C1234%2C526,2500; expires=Fri, 10-Jan-2014 19:21:53 GMT; path=/`

Comment: How is your question different from the two that you linked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should get cookies from request and set them on response.

There is magic code in `HttpResponse` that clones new cookies to request (and in your case probably does it in some way you don't expect) so developers can somewhat randomly pick where to read cookies from on server.

It may be cleaner to read cookies early in request lifetime (before any cookies set on response) and set cookies on response late (but not too late as it have to happen before first portion of response body flushed to client).